# How to convert custom fields array into the key value pair?

Tags: zapier

I have a trigger, which returning ar array of custom fields. each element of the array have a two keys `FIELD_VALUE` and `FIELD_NAME`.

When I am mapping these fields in an action there are only two field available :

1. `FIELD VALUES` ==> comma separated values of all custom fields key `FIELD_VALUE`, similarly
2. `FIELD NAMES` ==> comma separated values of all custom fields key `FIELD_NAMES`

I want to convert all of the fields in a `key:value` pair. So the value of `FIELD_NAME` will be a key and value of `FIELD_VALUE` will be a value.

[image: Here is the attachment of trigger response]

I have tried to use code by zapier but it is not working as expected:

Here is my JS code:

```js
var names = (inputData.names).split(',');

var values = ((inputData.values).toString()).split(',');

var obj = names.reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[index] }), {});
```

[image: My code by zapier script]
The problem is null values, Zapier removing null values from comma separated string.

Comment: @xavdid thanks for the edit, could you please also share a solution if you have.

Comment: can you update your question with the actual output from the code step? also, your output doesn't include `obj`, but presumably should?

Comment: Yes, I was removed it to check input fields value available at code step.

Comment: Please find below screenshot:
https://nimb.ws/OGoTHK
https://nimb.ws/2EDsYh

You can see there are 8 names attribute available while only 4 values are there. there must be an equal number of irems in both

Comment: You can see in values `null` are not available in response

Comment: what's the id of your zap?

Comment: Dupe of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59365846/1292652) asking for nulls to not be dropped

Comment: @xavdid Any possibility of this?